# c# attributes and reflection in MethodBody

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to determine what `attributes` are used inside a `MethodBody`?

For example:

```
void method1()
{
    method2();
}

[Attr()]
void method2()
{
   // NOP
}
```

Would there be any way for me to look at `method1()` and determine that it is using `method2()` or its associated attributes?

Comment: What do you mean by "attributes are used?"  The attribute isn't *used* on a call to method2.  More generally the question of determining which methods are called by a method is not as simple as you might think.  If you're asking "Which methods are called directly *in the lexical body* of a method, you can figure that out using ildasm at runtime.  If you're asking "Which methods are called during the execution of a method?" then you are out of luck, because that question is not answerable in general in finite time.

Comment: Roslyn will give you access to the call graph of code, so you could check all the methods that are *callable* indirectly by another method.  That might be what you're looking for, but that will give you methods that are never actually called.

Comment: See this question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/roslyn/thread/85a816cb-e931-4b49-893a-abbbf38c7a38

Comment: That requires a disassembler.  Not a feature of Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing especially the first part...

> Is it possible to determine what attributes are used inside a MethodBody?

... because even though method1() is calling method2(), and method2() is tagged with an attribute, in no sense is that attribute being *used* in method1().

> Would there be any way for me to look at method1() and determine that it is using method2() or its associated attributes?

The short answer is - at runtime - no.  You could of course manually tag method1() (and any other methods and any other methods) with something that denoted that they called method2() but I don't think this is what you're asking.

If you give us the context of what exactly you are trying to achieve it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Finding out that `method1` calls `method2` from anywhere in your code is hard and not something that I believe has been done before. It is not clear to me why you would want to do that.

Using only Reflection in C# it is not possible to find out that `method1` calls `method2`, as you can get only the raw binary representation of its Common Intermediate Language (CIL, the language used internally to represent all C#, VB, F# etc.. instructions).

```
byte[] methodIL = typeof(Program).GetMethod("method1")
    .GetMethodBody()
    .GetILAsByteArray();
```

However, [Mono Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) is a custom library designed to work with .Net assemblies and makes reading and working with the CIL of a method a lot easier. You could take a look at that and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Thats more or less what I expected.  I realize that I can go through the byte codes, but wasn't sure if the usage of attributes would allow me to look into a MethodBody with more detail.